# What if not use the setup() and closeup() method in MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Say I have a mapper as below, the Mapper class gets local top 10 for each mapper

```
public class TopTenMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {

    private TreeMap<Long, String> tmap;
    // Called once in the beginning before each map method
    @Override
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        tmap = new TreeMap<Long, String>();
    }

    // Called once for each key/value pair in the input split
    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] tokens = value.toString().split("\\t");
        String streetName = tokens[0];
        Long numCrimes = Long.parseLong(tokens[1]);
        tmap.put(numCrimes, streetName);
        if(tmap.size() > 10){
            tmap.remove(tmap.firstKey());
        }
    }

    // Called once at the end of the task
    @Override
    protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        for(Map.Entry<Long, String> entry : tmap.entrySet()){
            context.write(new Text(entry.getValue()), new LongWritable(entry.getKey()));
        }
    }
}
```

I got that the `setup()` is called once before the `map()`, and the `cleanup()` is called once before leaving the map task. But can I just put the code of setup() at the start of the map(), put code of cleanup() at the end of the map()?

```
public class TopTenMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {

    private TreeMap<Long, String> tmap;

    // Called once for each key/value pair in the input split
    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        tmap = new TreeMap<Long, String>();

        String[] tokens = value.toString().split("\\t");
        String streetName = tokens[0];
        Long numCrimes = Long.parseLong(tokens[1]);
        tmap.put(numCrimes, streetName);
        if(tmap.size() > 10){
            tmap.remove(tmap.firstKey());
        }

        for(Map.Entry<Long, String> entry : tmap.entrySet()){
            context.write(new Text(entry.getValue()), new LongWritable(entry.getKey()));
        }
    }
}
```

I think the tmap is still initialized at the every beninning of the map task, is it? What are the reasons and scenarios that I have to use `setup()` and `cleanup()` methods?

Answer (score 0):

`map()` is called once per key-value input pair. The `TopTenMapper` class itself (and therefore `setup()`) is only initialised once per map task.

In your second example, with `tmap = new TreeMap<Long, String>();` inside the `map()`, you'll never actually get the top ten, that map will only ever have one value in it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!